# Rendering unicode characters in pdf using java

Tags: java, pdf, oracle11g, character-encoding

We have a java application which creates pdf file by retrieving data from the database table. The data are stored in different languages like French, Italy, Portugal, Spain, etc. In development environment, it creates pdf content as in the database entry. But in UAT environment, it displays junk characters as in the the below UAT screenshot.

Please help me to fix this issue

**UAT screenshot:**

[image: UAT Screenshot]

**DEV Screenshot:**

[image: DEV Screenshot]

Comment: It seems more like the fault of the system than the java application. Did you try changing the character encoding of the system, you are running the application on, to `UTF-8` or `Unicode`?

Comment: Maybe a font is missing on the UAT environment.  Are you using itext or Apache FO?

Comment: The UAT problem clearly is UTF-8 data being interpreted as ISO-8859-1 (or another single byte encoding). Please provide relevant Java code and describe what library you are using for generating PDF. Oracle most likely isn't the problem as it never changes the interpretation of a given encoding. More likely, it's something like `String.getBytes()` where the default encoding is assumed and the default encoding is different from Dev to UAT.

Comment: It might also be due to different encoding configurations of the database, but it definitively is an encoding issue.